# How to remove the multiple of a function in Sympy

Tags: sympy

I am now making an ODE solver using Sympy. It can solve = Separable, Linear, Bernoulli, Second-Order Homogenous, Exact and Non Exact Equation, Nth Order Homogenous DE, Lagrange, Clairaut, 2nd and 3rd Order Nonhomogenous Diff. Eq, Can use undetermined coeff. in the form of: exp(x), cos(x), sin(x), x**n, exp(x)cos(x).

But for `2 * cos(x), 3 * exp(x)` the code does not understand when the code is multiplied by a number. Here is my question. How can I remove every coefficients. Are there any function or method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways depending on exactly what you are doing but e.g.:

```
In [124]: f = 2 * cos(x)

In [125]: f
Out[125]: 2⋅cos(x)

In [126]: c, m = f.as_coeff_Mul()

In [127]: c
Out[127]: 2

In [128]: m
Out[128]: cos(x)
```

Comment: That's so neat! Thanks a lot! It worked for me !